# Laravel tinker mode

Tags: laravel, tinker

If I run `php artisan tinker` the CLI will open with

```
Psy Shell v0.8.6 (PHP 7.0.8 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>>
```

Now I enter a word like 'test' and press the return key.

- What mode did I enter?
- How can I exit this mode? (ctrl+c exits tinker, but actually I only want to be able to execute commands again as usual which means I type in a command and when I press the return key it will be executed)
- How can I execute commands in this mode. If I press enter in this mode I will move to the next line, but the command is not executed.

Comment: Show the exact steps you took to enter the mode you're talking about.  Psy Shell should execute on enter by default.

Answer (score 1):

When I type run PsySH and then type `test`, I don't enter a different mode. I actually get an error that reads:

> PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in Psy Shell code on line 1

This might be a version issue.

**But...**

I think I know the mode you're talking about. You can enter that mode by typing one single quote `'` and pressing Enter.

What PsySH is doing is letting you supply input across multiple lines. If, on the next line you just type `';` you should see `"\n"` because it captured the Enter that you pressed.

If you want to exit this mode, you can either:

- Close whatever opening statement you made. You can **enter** this mode by typing "`function {` + Enter", "`for(;;) {` + Enter", the single-quote, and many other things. You need to type the appropriate closing for the statement you started. For a function, `}`. For a string, `'` or `"`, etc.
- Press ^D (Control+D). This will put you back at the PsySH prompt. This will also work in many regular system shells, because `^D` sends the `End-Of-File` character.

Answer (score 0):

- [Tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#introduction) is a command line tool that lets you interact with Laravel from the command line.
- You can exit tinker mode with either ctrl+c (as you mentioned) or typing `exit;` and hitting enter.
- Tinker is based on [PsySH](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh), you can think of this mode as a line-by-line interactive PHP parser.

So, for example, you can do something like this:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $testString = "test";
=> "test"
>>> echo $testString;
test⏎
=> null
>>> exit;
Exit:  Goodbye.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The only thing that is not working on my side is that if I write exit; and press enter, the next message will not be Exit: Goodbye. Instead I will enter a new line.

Comment: It could be version differences. I'm on PHP 5.6 and an older version of PsySH. I generally just use ctrl + c, personally.

Comment: What happens when you type the word 'test' as the first action after you start tinker and press enter. As next you type echo "hallo"; and press enter. Does this work on your side? On my side echo "hallo"; is not executed when I press enter. I would expect to get hallo⏎ back, but when I press enter I will go to the next line.

Comment: In the first case I get an error, in the second I get the expected text back. Have you tried updating? Your version may just not be working.

Answer (score 0):

**while you are in tinker just type**

> exit;